# Creating configurable pie chart using HTML java script

Tags: javascript, html, pie-chart

I am trying to develop a restful website using HTML5 CSS3. My requirement is that I need to develop a Pie Chart using the response data, which I am able to to do using [google library for charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart?hl=en)

Now the problem is that when the section of the pie chart is very small the user has to hover over that section to get the value as shown in the screen shot below. [image]

Now since it is a monitoring application where data changes continuously so user can't afford to  do that for example in the screen shot shown above for knowing the Absent percentage user has to hover over that element. The requirement is to have some thing like this as shown below where data is shown without needing to hover[image]

Now all such examples uses a paid library for industrial use which I can't afford. My question is is there any free library which can implement same or can the same be done using google charts with some customozation

My implementation of google library is pasted below

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", {
  packages: ["corechart"]
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Lunch', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Available', 11],
    ['Training', 2],
    ['Absent', 2],
    ['Sick', 2],
    ['Overtime', 7]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Employee Status',
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Supervising App</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>



  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width:100%; height :500px; overflow:hidden; float:left; border: 1px solid #2e638e;">
    <div id="piechart" class="draggableBoth"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Is there a way in I can make the tool tip permanent that will also keep the data shown permanently

Comment: You can use highChart, here is an [example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut) its pie chart.

Comment: By the way, your question is not the supposed topic in stackoverflow, see this [page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Under the title "Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above", item number 4.

Comment: @Qianyue thanks for the reply but High Charts is not free for commercial purpose check [link] (http://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts) . For the question being off topic I am sorry for that will keep that in mind , I am a newbie here you can guess that from my profile pic . Will keep that in mind in future

Comment: this is also nice for charts http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: @AmitSaha Thank you for pointing out that HighChart is not free for commercial use, I don't know that. [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) may help you? I'm not sure. But rephaeljs as lordkain mentions, it is for drawing. d3.js is powerful, it should satisfy your requirement, but it maybe too complexe to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Amit,

It depends on how much work you want to do to implement this feature. If you haven't seen it before [d3.js](http://d3js.org/), which is very powerful, flexible and free, would certainly give you what you need to create the chart and display the information precisely how you desire. However, if you have never used d3 it will certainly be a bit more work than the google library. As a long term solution I definitely recommend it though. 
I am not familiar with the google library but in scrolling through and seeing text on all the examples you might find that simply by adjust the font size properties listed you will get it to fit.